# What is the formula to find the slope of an angle if I have two x,y coordinates?

Tags: linear-algebra

How do I find the slope of an angle if I have two x,y coordinates?

Answer (score 3):

$m=(y_2-y_1)/(x_2-x_1)$ and $m=tan(\theta)$ where $\theta$ is the angle you are looking for.